# Replace `\n` in html page with space in python LXML

Tags: python, lxml

I have an unclear xml and process it with python lxml module. I want replace all `\n` in content with `space` before any processing, how can I do this work for text of all elements.

**edit**
my xml example:

```
<root>
    <a> dsdfs\n dsf\n sdf\n</a>
    <bds> 
        <d>sdf\n\n\n\n\n\n</d>
        <d>sdf\n\n\nsdf\nsdf\n\n</d>
    </bds>
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
</root>
```

and i wan't to get this in output when i print ittertext:

```
root = #get root element
for i in root.ittertext():
   print i

dsdfs  dsf  sdf
dsdfs  dsf  sdf
sdf  nsdf sdf
```

Comment: can you post an example of your _unclear_ xml?

Comment: Would the regex module be what you want? `import re; re.sub(i, '\n', ' ')`

Comment: I want to process with lxml after this change. I don't want change final text but i wan't change Element text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will parse the xml into a string, then replace `\n` with `space` and then write to a new xml file. You can do other processing in between, depending what exactly you want to do.

```
from lxml import etree 
tree = etree.parse('some.xml') 
root = tree.getroot()
# Get the whole XML content as  string
xml_in_str = etree.tostring(root)

# Replace all \n with space
new_xml_data = xml_in_str.replace(r'\n', ' ')

# Do the processing with the new_xml_data string which is formatted

# Maybe also write to a new XML file, without the \n
with open('newxml.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_xml_data)
```

`some.xml` looks like:

```
<root>
    <a> dsdfs\n dsf\n sdf\n</a>
    <bds> 
        <d>sdf\n\n\n\n\n\n</d>
        <d>sdf\n\n\nsdf\nsdf\n\n</d>
    </bds>
    <bds> 
        <d>sdf\n\n\n\n\n\n</d>
        <d>sdf\n\n\nsdf\nsdf\n\n</d>
    </bds>
    <bds> 
        <d>sdf\n\n\n\n\n\n</d>
        <d>sdf\n\n\nsdf\nsdf\n\n</d>
    </bds>
</root>
```

`newxml.xml` looks like:

```
<root>
    <a> dsdfs  dsf  sdf </a>
    <bds> 
        <d>sdf      </d>
        <d>sdf   sdf sdf  </d>
    </bds>
    <bds> 
        <d>sdf      </d>
        <d>sdf   sdf sdf  </d>
    </bds>
    <bds> 
        <d>sdf      </d>
        <d>sdf   sdf sdf  </d>
    </bds>
</root>
```

Answer (score -1):

What exactly is the code you have tried? strings are immutable for starters and there is no "replaceall" method in Python

```
for i in root_elem.itertext():
    j = i.replace('\n',' ')
    print(j+'\n')  # or some fp.write call to a new file
```

Comment: I want to process with lxml after this change

Comment: this code change result, but i want change text of Element class