# How to replace all `&#160;` with a space in an html file?

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'd like to replace all `&#160;` characters (or any variants like `&nbsp;` `&NonBreakingSpace;`) by a space character in the text part of an html file. (i.e., the ones returned by `text_content()` in `lxml`. Things in anything else like attributes should not be changed.)

Things like this can't gaurantee to only change the text part.

[Replace `\n` in html page with space in python LXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419567/replace-n-in-html-page-with-space-in-python-lxml/25421183)

What is the correct way to do so in lxml?

Comment: It sounds like you should take a string, and then do a replace all on a regex with a space?

Comment: The problem is how to iterate all elements and replace text of each element.

Comment: use `text = text.replace("&#160;", " ").replace("&nbsp;", " ")` before you use this text with `lxml`

Comment: How to iterate all text?

Comment: read text from file or page and replace it before you use `lxml` - you will have only one text to change it and there is no need to iterate it.

Comment: I mean the .text attribute of each htmlelement object in lxml.

Comment: not `.text`  frpm `lxml` but string from file - and later use this string with `lxml`

Answer (score 0):

You could use substitution from regular expressions for replacing the substring

```
import re
text = '''
I'd like to replace all &#160; characters (or any variants like &nbsp; &NonBreakingSpace;) by a 
space character in the text part of an html file. (i.e., the 
ones returned by text_content() in lxml. 
Things in anything else like attributes should not be changed.)
'''
out = re.sub(r"&\S*;", r"", text)
print(out)

>>I'd like to replace all  characters (or any variants like  ) by a 
space character in the text part of an html file. (i.e., the ones returned by text_content() in lxml. 
Things in anything else like attributes should not be changed.)
```

Comment: This has the same problem as the other answer.

Comment: then use HTML2Text python library to parse out just the text component of the HTML.

Get the text body, use RegEx to replace &\S*; and then replace each of these new text bodys in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file using the `open()` function and append them to a variable. You then can replace certain and write it back to the file. Here is an example:

```
#My File
myFile = 'myFile.html'

#Read the file and gather the contents
with open(myFile, "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)

#What we want to replace unwanted contents with
newContents = contents.replace('&#160;', ' ')

#Now write the file with the contents you want
with open(myFile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(newContents)
    print(newContents)
```

Comment: I only need to replace text not anything else. This can not guarantee not to change other things like attributes.

Comment: @user1424739 do you really have `'&#160;'` in attributes ? Maybe you make problem which doesn't exist.

Comment: @user1424739 do you have any attributes with &#160; in them? If not, I think this is a suitable answer.

Comment: I don't know whether there are HTML files that contain `&#160`. To know it, I have to check it for each input file, which I can't. Therefore, I don't want to make such an assumption.